# comma separated initializer for mutli-dimensional cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, multidimensional-array

In a number of tutorials [e.g. this one](http://www.bogotobogo.com/OpenCV/opencv_3_tutorial_creating_mat_objects.php) it is shown how to initialize an opencv Mat with a comma separated list.  However, when I attempt to do so with a multidimensional Mat, I get weirdness.

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    cv::Mat vect = (cv::Mat_<double>(2, 2, CV_8UC3) << 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
    std::cout << "vect = " << std::endl << " " << cv::format(vect,"python") << std::endl;
    return 12345;
}
```

Output:

```
vect = 
 [[1, 2], 
  [3, 4]]
```

Can one explicitly initialize a multidimensional Mat?

**EDIT:** Also I'm having trouble initializing it in other ways.

```
int main() {
    int data[2][2][3] = {
        {
            {1,2,3},
            {4,5,6}
        },
        {
            {7,8,9},
            {10,11,12}
        }
    };
    cv::Mat vect = cv::Mat(2, 2, CV_8UC3, data);
    std::cout << "vect = " << std::endl << " " << cv::format(vect,"python") << std::endl;
    return 54321;
}
```

Output:

```
vect = 
 [[[1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0]], 
  [[0, 0, 3], [0, 0, 0]]]
```

So the element in my input array at `[0][0][1]` ends up at `[0][1][1]` in the Mat??  What on earth is happening here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For template `Mat_` there's no overloaded function that takes `Mat_(int rows, int cols, int type)`, [source here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp#L2155).

```
cv::Mat vect = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,4) << 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
std::cout << "vect = " << std::endl << " " <<cv::format(vect,Formatter::FMT_PYTHON) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
vect = 
 [[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [5, 6, 7, 8],
 [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

For non-template Mat you need not give multidimensional array as data pointer argument, the `Mat::data` can be a continuous 1D data pointer. The `Mat` constructor will take care of channels, rows and columns as provided in the arguments.

```
uchar data[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
Mat vect(2,2,CV_8UC3,data);
std::cout << "vect = " << std::endl << " " << cv::format(vect,Formatter::FMT_PYTHON) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
vect = 
 [[[  1,   2,   3], [  4,   5,   6]],
 [[  7,   8,   9], [ 10,  11,  12]]]
```